# execute a sql command with Cursor -python with several variables

Tags: python, mysql

I use scripts in Python to execute Sql commands (with Cursor)

to execute a sql command with a single variable, I use this function:

```
def Execute (command,variable):
    global myresult , mycursor
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute(command,variable)
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    return myresult
```

example :

```
Subnet = Execute("SELECT subnet FROM network WHERE mykey = %s", Site)
```

but I can't find the function that allows me to pass several variables (2, 3 ..), I tried with this function, but it doesn't work:

```
def Execute (command,variable1,variable2):
    global myresult , mycursor
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute(command,variable1,variable2)
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    return myresult
```

I try to do : `Subnet = Execute("SELECT subnet FROM network WHERE mykey = %s AND ip = %s ", Site , Adress)`

Comment: Try: `Execute("SELECT subnet FROM network WHERE mykey=%s AND ip=%s", (Site , Adress))`

Comment: yes , I tried this but it doesnt work :(

Comment: What MySQL library (Python package) do you use to connect?

Answer (score 0):

`execute` expects the second argument to be a tuple of values to bind, and you passed two separate arguments. An elegant way of achieving what you want is using positional arguments:

```py
def Execute (command, *args):
    global myresult, mycursor
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute(command, args)
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    return myresult
```

Comment: thank you , and  how can I call this function ? , I tried : Execute("SELECT subnet FROM network WHERE mykey=%s AND ip=%s", (Site , Adress))   AND  Execute("SELECT subnet FROM network WHERE mykey=%s AND ip=%s", Site , Adress)  . But it doesnt work   ( mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'tuple' cannot be converted to a MySQL type )